# How to use a VirtualBox VM as a router to go outside network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, openwrt

I created an VirtualBox VM run openwrt-x86-generic-combined-ext4.vdi, 
In side the VM, I am able to ping the internal PCs after connected to VPN via vpnc.

now the question is from the Host machine how to setup to connect to the internal PCs via the VM Router.

from the Host, once I change the gateway to 192.168.1.2, i am not able to go out anyway.

thanks a lot.

PS, on host machine only one NIC which is wirelees NIC.  is there any Virtual NIC can be install and solve this problem??

```
HOST IP 192.168.1.33

Guest
config interface loopback
    option ifname   lo
    option proto    static
    option ipaddr   127.0.0.1
    option netmask  255.0.0.0
        config interface wan
        option ifname   eth0
        option proto    dhcp

config interface lan
    option ifname   eth1
    option type     bridge
    option proto    static
    option ipaddr   192.168.1.2
    option netmask  255.255.255.0
    option gateway  192.168.1.254
    option defaultroute 0
    option peerdns  01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand question entirely, but it seems to me that there is no difference between real PC and virtual one. Use Bridged Adapter mode, connect your machine to real network and use as real. Besides, you can use up to 4 adapters.

And if you want to use PC with linux as router, probably this may help [How to Enable IP Forwarding in Linux](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answering,  sorry for my poor english, i set TWO Adapter in VM already, inside the vm i can go google without any prob. but i want to use the host pc to connect to the google VIA the VM, but VMM is connect to google via my host pc... what i really want to do is, i setup vpnc in vm which connect to my company network, from the host i want to access public network, only for those company ip addr (172.0.0.0/8) i want  to go via vm router.

Comment: @user3724711 try to use Bridged Adapter mode. after enabling that you can change gateway on host without loosing internet on VM. traffic from your host will go to VM and from VM to network as if VM was another real machine (but with the same MAC address).

Comment: so basically you only want to be able to connect to your vpn using office ip address and able to surf the internet at the same time..??if you use the scheme that you described above, I think it will create an endless loop

Comment: yes, thants want i want, and yes it's endless loop...i am not able to go online...

Comment: @user3724711 This shouldn't be marked as the answer. This post is nothing related to the question and the comment is wrong. It won't be endless loop. I will provide a working solution later. I use this approach everyday.

Comment: @user3724711 I just realized this question is closed. So I can not add an answer to it... To be short, if you want your openwrt to become a router, you need two interfaces 'lan' and 'wan'. 'lan' attaches to Host-only Adapter and 'wan' attaches to Bridged Adapter. And then you set your Host's gateway and DNS to be lan's IP address. That's all. Because I can only add comment, this is just a short version of the solution.